# Can a Rust macro create new identifiers?

Tags: macros, code-generation, rust

I'd like to create a setter/getter pair of functions where the names are automatically generated based on a shared component, but I couldn't find any example of macro rules generating a new name.

Is there a way to generate code like `fn get_$iden()` and `SomeEnum::XX_GET_$enum_iden`?

Comment: is there a 2021 answer :D?

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Rust >= 1.31.0 I would recommend using my [`paste`](https://github.com/dtolnay/paste) crate which provides a stable way to create concatenated identifiers in a macro.

```
macro_rules! make_a_struct_and_getters {
    ($name:ident { $($field:ident),* }) => {
        // Define the struct. This expands to:
        //
        //     pub struct S {
        //         a: String,
        //         b: String,
        //         c: String,
        //     }
        pub struct $name {
            $(
                $field: String,
            )*
        }

        paste::paste! {
            // An impl block with getters. Stuff in [<...>] is concatenated
            // together as one identifier. This expands to:
            //
            //     impl S {
            //         pub fn get_a(&self) -> &str { &self.a }
            //         pub fn get_b(&self) -> &str { &self.b }
            //         pub fn get_c(&self) -> &str { &self.c }
            //     }
            impl $name {
                $(
                    pub fn [<get_ $field>](&self) -> &str {
                        &self.$field
                    }
                )*
            }
        }
    };
}

make_a_struct_and_getters!(S { a, b, c });
```

Answer (score 15):

My [**`mashup`**](https://github.com/dtolnay/mashup) crate provides a stable way to create new identifiers that works with any Rust version >= 1.15.0.

---

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate mashup;

macro_rules! make_a_struct_and_getters {
    ($name:ident { $($field:ident),* }) => {
        // Define the struct. This expands to:
        //
        //     pub struct S {
        //         a: String,
        //         b: String,
        //         c: String,
        //     }
        pub struct $name {
            $(
                $field: String,
            )*
        }

        // Use mashup to define a substitution macro `m!` that replaces every
        // occurrence of the tokens `"get" $field` in its input with the
        // concatenated identifier `get_ $field`.
        mashup! {
            $(
                m["get" $field] = get_ $field;
            )*
        }

        // Invoke the substitution macro to build an impl block with getters.
        // This expands to:
        //
        //     impl S {
        //         pub fn get_a(&self) -> &str { &self.a }
        //         pub fn get_b(&self) -> &str { &self.b }
        //         pub fn get_c(&self) -> &str { &self.c }
        //     }
        m! {
            impl $name {
                $(
                    pub fn "get" $field(&self) -> &str {
                        &self.$field
                    }
                )*
            }
        }
    }
}

make_a_struct_and_getters!(S { a, b, c });
```

Answer (score 9):

No, not as of Rust 1.22.

---

If you can use nightly builds...

Yes: `concat_idents!(get_, $iden)` and such will allow you to create a new identifier.

But no: the parser doesn't allow macro calls everywhere, so many of the places you might have sought to do this won't work. In such cases, you are sadly on your own. `fn concat_idents!(get_, $iden)(…) { … }`, for example, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little known crate [gensym](https://docs.rs/gensym/0.1.0/gensym/) that can generate unique UUID names and pass them as the first argument to a macro, followed by a comma:

> ```
> macro_rules! gen_fn {
>     ($a:ty, $b:ty) => {
>         gensym::gensym!{ _gen_fn!{ $a, $b } }
>     };
> }
>
> macro_rules! _gen_fn {
>     ($gensym:ident, $a:ty, $b:ty) => {
>         fn $gensym(a: $a, b: $b) {
>             unimplemented!()
>         }
>     };
> }
>
> mod test {
>     gen_fn!{ u64, u64 }
>     gen_fn!{ u64, u64 }
> }
> ```

If all you need is a unique name, and you don't care what it is, that can be useful. I used it to solve a problem where each invocation of a macro needed to create a unique static to hold a singleton struct. I couldn't use paste, since I didn't have unique identifiers I could paste together in the first place.