# Can I define a macro which will expand into a function call?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I've (naively) tried this, but it doesn't print anything to the screen:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    ($suffix:tt, $arg:expr) => {
        concat!("foo", $suffix, "(", $arg, ")");
    };
}

fn foo_i32(x: i32) {
    println!("i32 {}", x);
}

fn foo_bool(x: bool) {
    println!("bool {}", x);
}

fn main() {
    foo!("bool", true);
    foo!("i32", 1);
}
```

Comment: [Here's a more principled way of writing that using the type system to advantage.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2962e4463278bbdc4a780aa18fb39b48) Of course you can still define a `foo!` macro if you want, but using traits is more robust than naively gluing identifiers together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and no.

First of, `concat!` generates a string, so your code is essentially the same as if you wrote:

```rust
fn main() {
    "foobool(true)";
    "fooi32(1)";
}
```

which is a no-op.

To generate Rust code, the macro does not need to involve strings at all:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    ($suffix:tt, $arg:expr) => {
        $suffix($arg);
    };
}
```

which you could call as `foo!(foo_bool, true);`.

If however you want to construct the name `foo_bool` from `foo` and `bool`, you need to use [`concat_idents`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat_idents.html), which is currently unstable and unlikely to get stable any time soon (because it causes some hygiene issues):

```rust
#![feature(concat_idents)]

macro_rules! foo {
    ($suffix:tt, $arg:expr) => {
        concat_idents!(foo_, $suffix)($arg);
    };
}

fn foo_i32(x: i32) {
    println!("i32 {}", x);
}

fn foo_bool(x: bool) {
    println!("bool {}", x);
}

fn main() {
    foo!(bool, true);
    foo!(i32, 1);
}
```

Comment: [Can a Rust macro create new identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079909/155423)