# Match lifetimes in "struct field syntax" passed to macro_rules

Tags: rust, syntax, macros

I have defined the following macro because I need many slightly different structs with Serde serialization.

```rust
macro_rules! instantiate {
    (
        $(#[$struct_meta:meta])*
        $struct_name:ident {
            $(
                $(#[$field_meta:meta])*
                $field_name:ident: $field_type:ty = $field_value:expr,
            )+
        }
    ) => {{
        $(#[$struct_meta])*
        struct $struct_name {
            $(
                $(#[$field_meta])*
                $field_name: $field_type,
            )*
        }

        $struct_name {
            $($field_name: $field_value,)*
        }
    }};
}
```

And it should be used just like this:

```rust
instantiate! {
    #[derive(serde::Serialize)]
    RequestParams {
        #[serde(serialize_with="serialize_debug")]
        ids: Vec<Base62Uint> = version_ids
            .into_iter()
            .map(std::fmt::Display::to_string)
            .collect(),
    }
}
```

However, I have another use for it:

```rust
let (hash, kind) = match hash {
    FileHashes {
        sha512: Some(hash), ..
    } => (hash, "sha512"),
    FileHashes {
        sha1: Some(hash), ..
    } => (hash, "sha1"),
    _ => todo!(),
};

instantiate! {
    #[derive(serde::Serialize)]
    RequestParams {
        algorithm: &str = kind,
    }
}
```

I end up with the following error, which was expected:

```rust
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
   --> src/endpoints.rs:236:28
    |
236 |                 algorithm: &str = kind,
    |                            ^ expected named lifetime parameter
    |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
    |
88  ~         struct $struct_name<'a> {
89  |             $(
90  |                 $(#[$field_meta])*
91  |                 $field_name: $field_type,
92  |             )*
93  |         }
  ...
```

I want this macro to create a new lifetime for every `$field_name`, where the corresponding `$field_type` is a reference.

Here is what I have attempted:

```rust
$field_name: $(&$field_life:lifetime)? $field_type,
```

And stopped because I realized that would only capture the input lifetimes, which is less ergonomic than what I want, and I would end up with an ambiguity in the pattern because it input would be able to match either the `&$field_life:lifetime` portion or the `$field_type:ty`.

Comment: Your original macro already doesn't work for me. Please provid a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably tested on https://play.rust-lang.org/.

Comment: Apart of that, I suspect that replacing `&str` with `&'static str` should fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your minimal reproducible example is

```rust
macro_rules! instantiate {
    (
        $(#[$struct_meta:meta])*
        $struct_name:ident {
            $(
                $(#[$field_meta:meta])*
                $field_name:ident: $field_type:ty = $field_value:expr,
            )+
        }
    ) => {{
        $(#[$struct_meta])*
        struct $struct_name {
            $(
                $(#[$field_meta])*
                $field_name: $field_type,
            )*
        }

        $struct_name {
            $($field_name: $field_value,)*
        }
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let x = instantiate! {
        #[derive(serde::Serialize)]
        RequestParams {
            #[serde(default)]
            id: u32 = 10,
        }
    };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&x).unwrap());
}
```

```
{"id":10}
```

and your second example is, with the macro being identical:

```rust
fn main() {
    let (hash, kind) = (1234, "sha512");

    let x = instantiate! {
        #[derive(serde::Serialize)]
        RequestParams {
            algorithm: &str = kind,
        }
    };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&x).unwrap());
}
```

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:31:24
   |
31 |             algorithm: &str = kind,
   |                        ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
12 ~         struct $struct_name<'a> {
13 |             $(
14 |                 $(#[$field_meta])*
15 |                 $field_name: $field_type,
16 |             )*
17 |         }
 ...
```

---

### Solution #1 - the cheap solution without capturing lifetimes

```rust
fn main() {
    let (hash, kind) = (1234, "sha512");

    let x = instantiate! {
        #[derive(serde::Serialize)]
        RequestParams {
            algorithm: &'static str = kind,
        }
    };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&x).unwrap());
}
```

```
{"algorithm":"sha512"}
```

---

### Solution #2 - capturing lifetimes

```rust
macro_rules! instantiate {
    (
        $(#[$struct_meta:meta])*
        $struct_name:ident $(< $($lifetimes:lifetime),* >)? {
            $(
                $(#[$field_meta:meta])*
                $field_name:ident: $field_type:ty = $field_value:expr,
            )+
        }
    ) => {{
        $(#[$struct_meta])*
        struct $struct_name $(< $($lifetimes),* >)? {
            $(
                $(#[$field_meta])*
                $field_name: $field_type,
            )*
        }

        $struct_name {
            $($field_name: $field_value,)*
        }
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let (hash, kind) = (1234, "sha512".to_string());

    let x = instantiate! {
        #[derive(serde::Serialize)]
        RequestParams<'a> {
            algorithm: &'a str = &kind,
        }
    };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&x).unwrap());
}
```

```
{"algorithm":"sha512"}
```

Comment: I wanted the lifetimes to be captured off the fields and added automatically

Comment: Then I think my answer is that `macro_rules` is not powerful enough, you might have to use [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

`macro_rules!` cannot generate lifetimes, for the same reasons they cannot generate identifiers ([Can a Rust macro create new identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415011/can-a-rust-macro-create-new-identifiers)), because they cannot (without help) generate new token. You have to use a procedural macro for that.

You can use existing procedural macros that allow you to generate tokens, for example @dtolnay's [`seq-macro`](https://lib.rs/crates/seq-macro) crate, but it will raise another problem: how do you know where to put the lifetime? You can (partially, because you cannot identify all types requiring lifetimes) solve that by tt-munching and identifying types that require lifetimes (for example references), but this will make your macro *really* complex, even more than a proc macro. I do not recommend doing that.

Comment: In your first sentence, you mention that macro rules can't generate lifetimes for the same reason they can't generate identifiers. Please add that reason to your answer, and link to the source, and this will be the answer I was looking for.