# How do I keep an member variable that seems to need to outlive static?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I created a wrapper that will eventually provide a nice API for opening a file inside a tar file, as if it's a regular file. But the error I get is:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:26:43
   |
21 |     pub fn select_entry(&mut self, filename: &str) -> Result<()> {
   |                         - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
26 |                 self.current_entry = Some(Box::new(entry));
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Full code:

```rust
use std::io::Read;
use std::path::Path;
use tar::Archive;
use std::fs::File;
use anyhow::Result;

pub struct TarFileReader {
    archive: Archive<File>,
    current_entry: Option<Box<dyn Read>>,
}
impl TarFileReader {
    pub fn new(fname: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Result<Self> {
        let file = File::open(fname)?;
        let archive = Archive::new(file);
        Ok(TarFileReader {
            archive,
            current_entry: None,
        })
    }

    pub fn select_entry(&mut self, filename: &str) -> Result<()> {
        let entries = self.archive.entries()?;
        for entry in entries {
            let entry = entry?;
            if entry.path()?.ends_with(filename) {
                self.current_entry = Some(Box::new(entry));
                return Ok(());
            }
        }
        panic!("Entry not found in archive");
    }
}

impl Read for TarFileReader {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        match self.current_entry {
            Some(ref mut entry) => Ok(entry.read(buf)?),
            None => panic!("no entry selected"),
        }
    }
}
```

Really I want `TarFileReader::new()` to also find the file, but I'll be happy just understanding why the code doesn't build as is.

Comment: What does `entries()` return? Why do you need to box it? Using `Box` is fine, but you shouldn't need to re-box. Maybe instead of capturing a boxed element, instead store an index you can use to reference the entry.

Comment: Another self-referential struct. Try using [`ouroboros`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415011/can-a-rust-macro-create-new-identifiers). Although the newer [`nolife`](https://lib.rs/crates/nolife) may also be worth a shot.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks `nolife` is (currently) unsound.

Comment: Not sure if this really is a dupe, but the error message means that you're trying to put borrowed data (from &'1 mut self) into a Box, which can't have any borrowed data (as denoted by its 'static bound).

Comment: This is how it can look like with `ouroboros`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fa7e4d5e55bb6a3d4d2ede62d6c657d7.

Comment: The question has been closed as a duplicate of another. I'm failing to map that question to this one. My code doesn't directly use references at all, but presumably the `.entries()`, despite no ampersands in its docs, I guess must be using references: https://docs.rs/tar/latest/tar/struct.Archive.html

Comment: @tadman why do I need to box it? I'm just trying any way to make this build. Very possibly I don't need to box it.

Comment: The duplicate is about any field that references (i.e. contains a lifetime related to) another field, which applies well to your case, and it explains why it can't work and provide libraries that can be used.